# Why does my add function not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to get the value the user inputs into the modal input boxes and then add them to my state array. I have tried to take the value from the inputs and then push them into a clone of my state array and then set the state to the clone. However, this approach does not seem to work. I would appreciate if anyone could chime in.

```
    var Recipes = React.createClass({
    // hook up data model
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        recipeList: [
            {recipe: 'Cookies', ingredients: ['Flour', 'Chocolate']},
            {recipe: 'Pumpkin Pie', ingredients: ['Pumpkin Puree', 'Sweetened Condensed Milk', 'Eggs', 'Pumpkin Pie Spice', 'Pie Crust']},
            {recipe: 'Onion Pie', ingredients: ['Onion', 'Pie-Crust']},
            {recipe: 'Spaghetti', ingredients: ['Noodles', 'Tomato Sauce', 'Meatballs']}
          ]
      }
    },

    ingredientList: function(ingredients) {
     return ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
      return (<li key={index} className="list-group-item">{ingredient}</li>)
     })
    },

    eachRecipe: function(item, i) {
      return (
          <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading"><h3 key={i} index={i} className="panel-title">{item.recipe}</h3></div>
            <div className="panel-body">
              <ul className="list-group">
                {this.ingredientList(item.ingredients)}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      )
    },

    add: function(text) {
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var items = document.getElementById('ingredients').value.split(",");
      var arr = this.state.recipeList;
      arr.push({ recipe: name, ingredients: items });
      this.setState({recipeList: arr})
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
          <div>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Recipe</button>
          <div id="myModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div className="modal-dialog">

            <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 className="modal-title">Add a new recipe</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label forName="recipeItems">Recipe</label>
                        <input ref="userVal" type="recipe" className="form-control"
                        id="name" placeholder="Enter Recipe Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label for="ingredientItems">Ingredients</label>
                        <input ref="newIngredients" type="ingredients" className="form-control"
                            id="ingredients" placeholder="Enter Ingredients separated by commas"/>
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.add} type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
          {
            this.state.recipeList.map(this.eachRecipe)
          }
          </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Recipes />,
    document.getElementById('master')
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that whenever you click the button the form is submitted and the page reloads.

One solution is to take the `onClick={this.add}` out of the button and add `onSubmit={this.add}` at the `<form>` tag instead.

So, at the `add()` function you do:

```
add: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = e.target;
  var name = form.name.value;
  var items = form.ingredients.value.split(",");
  var arr = this.state.recipeList;
  arr.push({ recipe: name, ingredients: items });
  this.setState({recipeList: arr});
},
```

First, you call `e.preventDefault()` so your form won't reload the page. Second, you could use the `target` to access the input value through theirs `name`s attribute and set the state.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that can be improved in your code.

```
  add: function(text) {
    ...
    arr.push({ recipe: name, ingredients: items });
    this.setState({recipeList: arr})
  }
```

By using the `push()` method on your array you are essentially modifying the component's `state` by pushing the new item into it. It's strongly advised that you don't mutate your React component's state directly without using the [`setState` method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate).

A way to fix this would be by creating a new array in which you will copy all of the existing recipes plus the new recipe you are adding.

If you are using ES6/2015 it's even [easier](http://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/#Arrays) to achieve this:

```
add: function(text) {
  ...
  var newRecipe = { 
    recipe: name, 
    ingredients: items 
  };
  this.setState({ recipeList: [...this.state.recipeList, newRecipe] });
}
```

That way you don't modify the component's state before calling `setState()` method thus keeping it intact.

**Next**

```
add: function() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var items = document.getElementById('ingredients').value.split(",");
  ...
}
```

Try as much as possible to use the `Refs` (references) to access your input nodes, that way you don't have to use `getElementById` because it is more in line with the rest of your react code.

```
add: function(text) {
  var name = this.refs.userVal.value;
  var items = this.refs.newIngredients.value.split(",");
  ...
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
        <input 
          ref="userVal" 
          placeholder="Enter Recipe Name"
        />
        <input 
          ref="newIngredients" 
          placeholder="Enter Ingredients separated by commas"
        />
      ...
    </div>
  );
});
```

**And lastly**

To prevent the `Button` element from submitting the form and taking you to another page, which is what happening here, you could set the button's `type` attribute to `button` and it should no longer submit the form. [By default](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) a button element is of type `submit`.

```
<button onClick={this.add} type="button" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

And so by doing this you won't need to "prevent" the default action from occurring (which is to submit the form), using the `Event.preventDefault()` method in your `onClick` function handler.

Here is a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/celihefifa/edit?js,output) link with the above changes you could look at.

Comment: Thank you so much, I definitely understand you're approach and why. I can't believe it was such a simple solution!